# VPN in Google Cloud parameters

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-vpn

I'm configuring a VPN connection in hybrid Connectivity on Google cloud Platform. Are the following parameters supported by VPN Google cloud platform?

Encryption Algorithm, ESP-AES-SHA256
Diffie-Hellman Group,Group 2 ( 1024 bits )

I try to configure it, but the errors returned:

```
parsed CREATE_CHILD_SA response 31 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify, no CHILD_SA built
The peer gateway notifies: Proposal mismatch in CHILD SA (phase 2), Please look at peer logs.
failed to establish CHILD_SA, keeping IKE_SA
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud VPN supports the [following](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers) ciphers and configuration parameters for peer VPN devices or VPN services.